# disable keyboard in react native while selecting from dropdown or picker?

Tags: react-native

how can I  disable the keyboard when the user click the dropdown or the picker ?
 The keyboard triggered by the input field is not closing while I click the picker or dropdown

```
<View picker style={style.PickerBox} >
                  <Picker
                    mode="dropdown"
                    iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
                    placeholder="Select Type"
                    onValueChange={Type => this.setState({ Type })}
                    selectedValue={this.state.shopType}
                    style={style.Picker}
                  >
                    {this.state.shopTypesArray.map(value => {
                      //loop the dropdown
                      return (
                        <Picker.Item label={value.value} value={value.value} />
                      );
                    })}
                  </Picker>
                </View>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Keyboard.dismiss()` when you click on the dropdown/picker:

```
import { Keyboard } from "react-native"

...

yourFunc = () => {
    Keyboard.dismiss()
    //Your logic 
}
```

Source: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard

This will be triggered when you change the value inside the `Picker`:

```
<Picker
   mode="dropdown"
   iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
   placeholder="Select Type"
   onValueChange={Type => {
       Keyboard.dismiss()
       this.setState({ Type })
  }}
  selectedValue={this.state.shopType}
  style={style.Picker}
>
```

Comment: how to trigger keyboard.dismiss() when we click a picker or dropdown ?

Comment: If you show some code i could help you better, I dont know how you have implemented your code or what you are using

Comment: I updated my answer, see if it works the way you expect

Comment: but I need to dismiss the keyboard as soon as we click the picker

Comment: I searched a bit and can't seem to find a way to detect the onPress event on your picker. if you are using a scrollView you can simply use the prop keyboardShouldPersistTaps but if not you don't now when a user click on your Picker.  For the ScrollView solution you just need to change it to `<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled" />. If not, you need to use a thirdParty library for the picker